# Removing compatibility mode on 1000+ word documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, compatibility

I have a folder containing about 1200 word documents that are all saved in Compatibility Mode. Does anyone know of a way to convert every one of these files so that the documents are no longer in Compatibility Mode?

Answer (score 0):

Open up a cmd window in your folder and type `dir /s /b >>` filename.txt to get a plaintext list of all the files in the path.  That will give a textfile listing all files in the directory.

Use that as the input for the following

Since you're going to do it on 1000 files, I would set a break point at `doc.close` to test it out on the first few if I were you.

```
Sub SaveAsDocX(FileListFullPath As String)
    'for saving to new filename
    Dim newname As String
    'array of docs, items in that array, document object from those items
    Dim docs As Variant
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim doc As Document

    docs = getfiles(FileListFullPath)

    For Each item In docs
        If Right(item, 4) = ".doc" Then
            Set doc = Application.Documents.Open(FileName:=item)
            doc.Activate

            newname = item & " - updated.docx"

            'first save as new format then update compatibility, then save again
            doc.SaveAs2 FileName:=newname, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
            ActiveDocument.SetCompatibilityMode (wdCurrent)
            doc.SaveAs2 FileName:=newname, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault

            doc.Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub



Function getfiles(Optional FileName As String = "Dir.txt")
    Dim FileList() As String

    Open FileName For Input As #1
    FileList = Split(Input$(LOF(1), #1), vbCrLf)
    Close #1

    getfiles = FileList

End Function
```